# Error Message SystemLimitException

Tags: unit-test, governorlimits

Below is my Test class code and when I run the test class I am coming across this error

> System.LimitException: Too many query rows: 50001
>
> Stack Trace    Class.Testclass_StagingShippingAddressHandler.Test_ShippingAddressHandlerMethod: line 126, column 1

Below is my code can anyone say why and whats the issue

```
@istest(SeeAllData=true)
Public class Testclass_StagingShippingAddressHandler{
    Public static testMethod void Test_ShippingAddressHandlerMethod(){
        
        Profile pId =[Select id from Profile where name = :'System Administrator'];
        Profile pId1 =[Select id from Profile where name = :'Outside Sales'];  
        List<User> usList = new List<user>();
        User u=new User();
        u.LastName='Test';
        u.Alias='testuser';
        u.Email='test.user@stemcell.com';
        u.Username='user.test@stemcell.com';
        u.CommunityNickname='UserA';
        //Inserting a Role 
        UserRole r = new UserRole(DeveloperName = 'MyCustomRole', Name = 'My Role');
        insert r;
        u.EmailEncodingKey='ISO-8859-1';
        u.TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles';
        u.LocaleSidKey='en_US';
        u.LanguageLocaleKey='en_US';
        u.ProfileId = pId.Id;  
        insert u;            
        System.runAs(u){
            User u1=new User();
            u1.LastName='Test1';
            u1.Alias='tuser1';
            u1.Email='test.user1@stemcell.com';
            u1.Username='test.user1@stemcell.com';
            u1.CommunityNickname='UserB';
            //Inserting a Role 
            UserRole r1 = new UserRole(DeveloperName = 'CustomRole', Name = 'Rep Role');
            insert r1;
            u1.EmailEncodingKey='ISO-8859-1';
            u1.TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles';
            u1.LocaleSidKey='en_US';
            u1.LanguageLocaleKey='en_US';
            u1.ProfileId = pId.Id;              
            insert u1; 
            integer batchSize = 200;
            
            //Inserting recordtypes
            RecordType RT = [select id from RecordType where name ='Location' and sobjecttype = 'Territory_Component__c']; 
            RecordType RT_cust = [select id from RecordType where name ='Customer' and sobjecttype = 'Territory_Component__c']; 
            RecordType RT_exp = [select id from RecordType where name ='Export' and sobjecttype = 'Territory_Component__c'];
            RecordType RT_Par= [select id from RecordType where name ='Parent' and sobjecttype = 'Territory_Component__c']; 
            
            //Inserting Territory
            Territory__c territory = new Territory__c();
            territory.name = 'CAWESTCA';
            territory.Fiscal_Year__c = '2016';
            territory.Active__c=true;
            insert territory;
            
            //Inserting a Territory Component
            Territory_Component__c TC = new Territory_Component__c();
            TC.SoldInCountry__c = 'AUSTRALIA';
            TC.SoldInTerritoryId__c = TERRITORY.ID;
            TC.State__c = 'ACT';
            TC.Country__c ='AUSTRALIA';
            insert TC;
            
            //Inserting a Territory Component
            Territory__c territory1 = Test_CustomObjectUtil.createTerritory('USCASTEST',false);
            insert territory1;
            List<Territory_Component__c> terrCompList = new List<Territory_Component__c>();
            Territory_Component__c territoryComponent1 = Test_CustomObjectUtil.createTerritoryComponentLocation(territory1.Id, RT.Id, 'UNITED STATES', 'CA','9999',false);    
            Territory_Component__c territoryComponent2 = Test_CustomObjectUtil.createTerritoryComponentLocation(territory1.Id, RT.Id, 'UNITED STATES', 'CA',Null,false);    
            Territory_Component__c territoryComponent3 = Test_CustomObjectUtil.createTerritoryComponentLocation(territory1.Id, RT.Id, 'UNITED STATES', Null,Null,false);    
            //Territory_Component__c territoryComponent4 = Test_CustomObjectUtil.createTerritoryComponentExport(territory1.Id, RT_exp.Id, NUll,'UNITED STATES', false);    
            terrCompList.add(territoryComponent1);
            terrCompList.add(territoryComponent2);
            terrCompList.add(territoryComponent3);
            //terrCompList.add(territoryComponent4);
            insert terrCompList;
            
            //Test retrieval of reps for one territory
            Sales_Territory_Mapping__c stmFSALM = Test_CustomObjectUtil.createSalesTerritoryMapping(u1.Id, 'FSALM', territory1.Id);
            Sales_Territory_Mapping__c stmFSALCS = Test_CustomObjectUtil.createSalesTerritoryMapping(u1.Id, 'FSALCS', territory1.Id);
            stmFSALCS.Account_Owner__c = true;
            update stmFSALCS;
            
            //Inserting a Custom setting record
            /*  Switch_Fiscal_year__c SFY = new Switch_Fiscal_year__c();
SFY.Name ='Switch Fiscal year';
SFY.Current_Fiscal_year__c = '2020';
SFY.Staging_Year__c = '2021';
insert SFY;
SFY.Staging_Year__c = '2022';
update SFY; */
            
            //Inserting Shipping Address record
            List<Shipping_Address__c >ShipAdList =  new List<Shipping_Address__c >();
            Shipping_Address__c ShipAd = new Shipping_Address__c();
            ShipAd.Name = 'CAWEST';
            ShipAd.Country__c='CANADA';
            ShipAd.State__c='BC';
            insert ShipAd;             
            ShipAd.Territory__c = 'CAWESTCA';
            update ShipAd;
            ShipAdList.add(ShipAd); 
            
            //Inserting Staging Shipping Address record
            List<Shipping_Address__c >ShipAdList1 =  new List<Shipping_Address__c >();
            Shipping_Address__c ShipAd1 = new Shipping_Address__c();
            ShipAd.Name = 'CAWEST';
            ShipAd.Country__c='CANADA';
            ShipAd.State__c='BC';
            insert ShipAd1;             
            ShipAd.Staging_Territory__c = 'CAWESTCA';
            update ShipAd1;
            ShipAdList.add(ShipAd); 
            
            
            /*
//Inserting Shipping Address record
Shipping_Address__c ShipAd1 = new Shipping_Address__c();
ShipAd1.Name = 'CAWEST';
ShipAd1.Country__c='CANADA';
ShipAd1.State__c='BC';
insert ShipAd1;             
ShipAd.Territory__c = 'CAWESTCA';
update ShipAd1;
ShipAdList.add(ShipAd1); 
*/
            Set<String> testSet = new Set<String>();
            List<Int360_Master_Queue_Stage__c> queueList = [SELECT Reference_Value__c
                                                            FROM Int360_Master_Queue_Stage__c];
            Set<String> referenceSet = new Set<String>();
            for(Int360_Master_Queue_Stage__c queue : queueList) {
                referenceSet.add(queue.Reference_Value__c);
            }
            for(String id : testSet) {
                System.assert(referenceSet.contains(id));
            }
            
            
            
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: If the posted answer [addressed your problem](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. If you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `@isTest(SeeAllData=true)` combined with an unlimited query: `[SELECT Reference_Value__c FROM Int360_Master_Queue_Stage__c];`.

Preferably, you should remove the SeeAllData attribute, so that you'll be isolated from your live data.

Comment: Okay I will try to work with no (SeeAllData=true) Annotation.